# ListviewItem Clone, associated name gets lost

Tags: c#, clone, listviewitem

I just figured out a problem i have got which is caused by cloned `ListViewItem` and `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem` which loose their `Name` property after the `ListViewItem` got cloned.

Am i missing something or is this a normal behaviour?

What i'm doing is

```
ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvw.Items[position].Clone();
```

after that, all `Name` properties have been set to their defaults, `String.Empty`, at `item` and `item.SubItems`.
But i thought, `Clone()` will create a 1:1 clone of the existing item, and so the name should be taken with also, because it has been set before i call clone, i debugged this several times, so that cannot be the problem.

I'm not looking for a solution how to avoid this, that's easy if you know that there are such "problems", i just want to understand why this happens.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I think that's a normal behavior, you can always name your cloned item, but if the name is copied, what if you add that cloned item to the same ListView with the original item? there will be 2 items with the duplicated name and maybe this causes some conflict, I'm not sure if there is some exception thrown, even if it's not thrown, the duplicated names will become meaningless.

Comment: @King King, after looking at ListViewItem.Clone Method in MSDN (the URL is rather long for a comment) i think you're right, although the MSDN is not quite consequent in its description. In the first sentence it says: "Creates an identical copy of the item." But in detailed explanation it says: "An object that represents an item that has the same text, image, and subitems associated with it as the cloned item." Well, you just need to know about, but for me clone should take everything as it states by the meaning of itself.